# Regex for validating URL with brackets in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex

In my app, I need to validate the URL that the user inputs into the textField. Valid URL might have brackets with number at the end, for example, "https://stackoverflow.com(24)". The URL without brackets, for example, "https://stackoverflow.com", is also valid.

I use this code for validating URL without brackets, and it works:

```
extension String {
    
    func validateUrl() -> Bool {
        let urlRegEx =
            "^(http|https|ftp)\\://([a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-]+(\\:[a-zA-Z0-9\\.&amp;%\\$\\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.(com|ru|kz|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\,\\?\\'\\\\\\+&amp;%\\$#\\=~_\\-]+))*$"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx).evaluate(with: self)
    }
    
}
```

However, it doesn't validate URLs with brackets. What should I end at the end of this regex to make it work for both types of URLs? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does it mean validate `URL`? Can't you just try to initialize a `URL` with your string? If it returns `nil` it is not valid.

Comment: you can just add `(\(\d+\))?` at the end, is there something i am missing?

Comment: What a huge regex pattern . Maybe just `return URL(string: self) != nil` is sufficient. The init method returns `nil` if the URL is invalid.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to validate with your huge regex pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `(?:\(\d+\))?` before `$`:

```swift
"^(http|https|ftp)://([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(?::[a-zA-Z0-9.&amp;%$-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.(com|ru|kz|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(?::[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.,?'\\\\+&amp;%$#=~_-]+))*(?:\\(\\d+\\))?$"
```

The `(?:\(\d+\))?` matches an optional occurrence of a sequence of `(`, one or more digits, `)`.

Note:

- `{1}` is always redundant in regex, remove these
- You do not need to escape a lot of chars that are special *inside* square brackets, like `.`, `;`, `$`, etc. Only `[`, `]`, `^`, `-`, `]` and `\` are special inside square brackets
- `-` at the end of the character class (the `[...]` thing) does not have to be escaped
- I replaced some capturing groups with non-capturing as you are not extracting part of the match.